# Что не правильно?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

  const char lboVar(int a,  int b) {
       if (a == b) {
                return 1;
       }
       return a > b 
                 ? a + " " + lboVar(a - 1, b) 
                 : a + " " + lboVar(a + 1, b);

    }
    int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    lboVar(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a + " "` - что это за дичь?

Comment: Вы это компилировали?...

Comment: да но [Error] invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]

Comment: И это не натолкнуло вас на определенные мысли? что вы пытаетесь сделать нечто очень странное?... Кстати, в чем ваша задумка - ну, что должна делать программа?..

Comment: Даны два целых числа A и В (каждое в отдельной строке). Выведите все числа от A до B включительно, в порядке возрастания, если A < B, или в порядке убывания в противном случае.

Comment: *Что не правильно?* Явно видно, что - как по такому заголовку понять, что внутри обсуждается? А еще неправильно написано слово "неправильно" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы хотели так?

```
void lboVar(const int a, const int b) {
    std::cout << a << ' ';
    if (a == b)         
        return;
    return (a > b) ?
        lboVar(a - 1, b)
        : lboVar(a + 1, b);
}
int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    lboVar(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void lboVar(int A, int B)
{
    for(int i = A; i != B; (A<B)?i++:i--) cout << i << " ";
    cout << B << endl;
}
```

Comment: такое вариант у меня тоже было но надо с помощью рекурсий решать

Comment: нужно вопрос оформлять так, чтобы потом не выяснять что надо и что не надо

Comment: ты лучше помоги как удалить этот вопрос

Answer (score 1):

у вас ошибка в этом месте:

```
a + " "
```

переменная a - целочисельный тип, 
" " - все что в двойных кавычках это константный указатель на строку. Чтобы ваш код заработал, нужно чтобы был определен оператор + для левого значения int и правого значения const char*. Но если всего лишь нужно добавление ascii- символа пробела, то замените просто двойные кавычки на такие: ' '.